# Change event of textbox or Click button of Button . Inconsistent behavior in called method in Angular 5.5

Tags: angular, onclick, onchange

I have a form with 3 control. 2 Textboxes say A, B and Save button in an Angular form.
Now, when a user changes anything in textbox A and moves to different textbox; an onChange event we are calling one web API method which returns updated value for Textbox B. This works fine.

The issue crops when the user types something in Textbox A (Note: onchange is not yet called.It gets called only when moved to different control) and instead of doing tab simply clicks on save button. At this point, sometimes onchange and save both methods are getting called and sometimes only onchange.
Not sure why this is occurring.

```
<text name='TextboxA' [(ngmodel)]='valueA' (change)='callwebapi(someval)'> 
</text> 
<text name='TextboxB' [(ngmodel)]='valueB' > </text>
<button (click)='savebothAB()'></button>
```

Please note Textboxes are number only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Found solution, Just in case if any one stuck with same question. Angular calls both OnChange and Button click consistently and it has to be handled through callback or promise

Answer (score 0):

Try using other kind of events, like:

```
<text name='TextboxA' [(ngmodel)]='valueA' (blur)='callwebapi(someval)'> 
</text>
```

This is going to trigger your api call anytime the textbox loses focus. I don't know if this is the desireb behavior, but you should work with other types of events to triiger your api call.

Take a look at this guide to see all possible event handles:

https://angular.io/guide/user-input